# Is there benefit of use of red light over dim white light when interacting with rodents in the dark phase?

Tags: vision, circadian-rhythms, rodents

I've come across some "percieved wisdom" that rats and mice do not "see" red visible light and so use of this wavelength will allow humans to interact with rats in their active nocturnal phase without affecting their circadian rhythms.  Having gone to read the evidence for myself of this I can see evidence that red visible light does indeed impact rodent circadian rhythm ([Dauchy et al J Am Assoc Lab Anim Sci. 2015 Jan; 54(1): 40–50](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4311741/)) so is not a "fix" to allow us to see without the rodent being impacted.  What I cannot see is if there is any "benefit" to use of red vs white light if it has to be used or whether it just has the same impact and the only negative is the human can see less!!!!  Can anyone help ?

Comment: I propably can answer this qustion. But still i need to be 100% sure, what are you exacly want to know. Your question is: Why does chronobiologiest use in experiment red part of visible spectrum, but not whole light spectrum (white light)? Am i correct?